# How to fit page to Silverlight WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, webbrowser-control

I use WebBrowser Silverlight 4 control to load some page:

```
<WebBrowser Height="350" Name="webBrowser" Width="400" />
...
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://mail.live.com"));
```

But page loads with horizontal and vertical scroll bars. So I'm trying to find some ways to get actual size of loaded page (then I can change Height/Width of control) **OR** change scale of loaded page (to fit it to the actual WebControl control). Is it possible to do with standard WebControl methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web browser component in Silverlight is a COM component that is wrapped by a Silverlight control.

You have two options.  1)  Make the web site fluid inside the browser so that it will shrink with the browser.

Or

2) The only way that you could "shrink" the web site would be to set the Zoom.  There is a link to do this here by tricking the mouse scroll wheel into zooming it for you.

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/200177/466986.aspx

Comment: It would be nice to access the DOM of the embedded page to get the dimensions but that is restricted, so I think yours is the best workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Got you.
Usually you can do that using the ViewBox, but it doesn't work with Webbrowser unfortunately. I guess you will have to wait for the next version of Webbrowser :(

--Old answer below:

I'm not sure if i understood your problem correctly, do you want the webbrowser to fit its parent container?

Maybe using HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment like this?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
     <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Could you explain better?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not exactly what I need. 
So, details. For example: I'm trying to open some web-page with WebBrowser control instance with Height="600" and Width="900". Page opens correctly. Then I decide to change size of WebBrowser control and set Height="300" and Width="600". Of course entire page can't displays inside WebBrowser and scrollbars appears. SO I'm seeking for a way to remove these scrollbars (and display entire page). Most preferable way - change scale of the web page inside WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink a WebBrowser control by wrapping it into a ViewBox control and then setting the Width and Height on the ViewBox instead of the web browser. You will also need to set the Stretch property on the viewbox to Uniform.

```
<ViewBox x:Name="MyViewBox" Width="350" Height="350" Stretch="Uniform">
    <WebBrowser x:Name="MyWebBrowser" Source="...." />
</ViewBox>
```

HTH.

If this helps, please mark as answer. Thanks,